# Are Unicode characters valid in variable names?

Tags: javascript

I know you can't do

```
var foo = {};
foo.✈ = "NOT VALID";
```

but you can do

```
var foo = {};
foo["✈"] = "VALID";
```

`foo["✈"]` definitely makes `✈` a property of `foo` and `✈` can definitely be used like a variable but, technically speaking, is `✈` a "variable"?

Comment: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: Yes, they are, read the spec http://es5.github.io/#x7.6. 'any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.
'

Comment: variable names and object properties are not the same thing

Comment: not looking for a history of javascript. just want a yes no answer.

Answer (score 0):

no. ✈ in your array is not a variable. it is exactly ✈

you may make it a variable if you wnat though.

```
var ✈ = "something";
```

is perfectly fine

Comment: I think he is trying to make ✈ as an property on object foo

Comment: array? ... trying to make?

Comment: how to draw the aeroplane?